# check the data from row by row of two dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am new to python and pandas. Here I have two dataframes which are

df1 =

```
A1    B1     A2  B2  A3  B3
null  null   0   2    7   2
103    22     91  0   88  0 
137    22    131  2   126  2
161    2     159  2   157  2

df2 = 

 A4     B4      A5     B5       A6     B6
103    2200     109    0       113    2200
113    2200     126   2200     131    2200
157    200      159   200      161    200
170    200      184    0       195    200
```

So, Here I am trying to take the values row by row.

So from df1 I am trying to take `A1 and from df2 A4`

so at first it will be like , `null -> 103` Now there is a chance that values in A1 can be null so that I have to take the `A3 value` if not the A1.

So,It is like highest value from `df1 of A1`

```
and lowest value from df2 of A4
```

output will be like

```
start   end    sval eval
7        103    2    2200
103      113   22    2200
137      157   22    200
161      170   2     200
```

How can I get this result ?

Comment: `pd.concat([df1,df2], axis = 1).apply(lambda x : pd.Series({'start': x['A1'] if not np.isnan(x['A1']) else x['A3'], 'end': x['A4']}), axis=1)`

Comment: If that value in `A1` is null, what determines the column you take the value from? Why, in your example, is it `A3` and not any other column. Can there be a null in `A3`? Is there a particular reason why you are using `null` and not `NaN`?

Comment: @splash58 Is there any way though which I can add the B1 and B4 values as well in the same way or the B values of start and end in the new column

Comment: what a problem? if you print `pd.concat([df1,df2], axis = 1)` you see that rows contain all column value and you can use any combinations of them

Comment: Yes @AlexanderCécile you are right It can be from either A2 or A3  whichever is the higest

Comment: @ganeshk Okay, that’s important information. Are there any other details you can provide?

Comment: and same goes for A4 as well.. it will be from A4 primaraly but if not then A5 or A6 but it will be the lowest value

Comment: @ganeshk so it’s the lowest non-null value of all the `Ax` values for that row? Is it the lowest or the highest? Your comment seems to contradict your post.

Comment: Hmm or do you mean the _first_ non-null value?

Comment: I mean from df1 is the highest value and from df2 it is the lowest value

Comment: *from df2 it is the lowest value* - `103    2200     109    0       113    2200` => 0

Comment: it is 103 , It will be always be from Ax value

Comment: Do you have a list of a the `Ax` columns anywhere in your program, or do we have to iterate the column names and check them?

Comment: we have to iterate and check